# bigcartel : display secondary image.product

Tags: bigcartel

I am preparing a small shop and want to move the product page by displaying only the second image uploaded (this one is different from the thumbnail)
I'm looking to display the secondary image on a product.

Something like `{{ product.image[1] }}`, but it doesn't work. Can someone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
<img src="{{ product.images[1] | product_image_url }}" />
```